# How to get length of div with particular class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some problem in getting the length of the div with particular class.

HTML

```
<div class="sampleDiv">
    <div class="e"></div>
    <div class="e"></div>

    <div class="list-tasks12">
        <div class="slot"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="list-tasks12">
        <div class="slot"></div>
        <div class="slot"></div>
        <div class="slot"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
alert($(".sampleDiv").find('.list-tasks12:nth-child(1)').find('.slot').length)
```

Here it is showing length as zero which is wrong.

Please help what i am doing wrong

[Demo Here](https://jsfiddle.net/4qrc8hw8/)

Comment: Use `:eq` in place of nth-child.  [`$(".sampleDiv").find('.list-tasks12:eq(1)').find('.slot').length`](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/4qrc8hw8/1/) or `$('#sampleDiv .list-tasks12:last .slot').length`

Comment: your `.list-tasks12` divs are the 3rd and 4th child respectively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(".sampleDiv").find('.list-tasks12').eq(0).find('.slot').length
```

Answer (score 1):

The alert is not working properly because the `<div class="e"></div>` are also children of the parent div. You should remove them from the `<div class="sampleDiv">` container or count them also - so if you want the first child `<div  class="list-tasks12">` you should count the two `<div class="e"></div>` containers and use the following script:

```
alert($(".sampleDiv").find('.list-tasks12:nth-child(3)').find('.slot').length);
```

For the second `<div  class="list-tasks12">` child you should use:

```
alert($(".sampleDiv").find('.list-tasks12:nth-child(4)').find('.slot').length);
```

Here is a jsfiddle for it: https://jsfiddle.net/b1hsp30j/

Comment: Thanks for detail explanation.